# What's the good practice on UI design?

Tags: wpf

Will it be a good idea to separate the GUI with Data model, say, design the GUI Application using .NET WPF, but all the data keeping & processing are happened in BPL library (written in Delphi)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a good idea.

Tier separation is a logical concern, and is primarily managed via namespaces. If you take a well built WPF application you have quite a few of these. `View`, `ViewModel`, `Model`, `Command`, and `Convertors` should probably appear in every non-trivial application, and since they are all required for the application to run there is no need to separate them.

Physical separation into different assemblies is then simply a packaging consideration. If you have multiple applications and you think you can re-use some code then it gets pulled into a different physical assembly, but designing it separately is over-design.

Consider an application that has a unit test suite. Now you have two ways to run the code. You can run the application as a user would, or you can run the test runner and let the tests exercise your code as designed. Here we would have at least two assemblies. The testing code isn't needed when you are just using the application, so it can be separate. However, the application itself has no need to be anything more than a single assembly, so good practice says save yourself the effort.

*Now I'll preface this part with I've never tried to link C# and Delphi*, but it is just adding to the complexity that you will face. Do you ***NEED*** to use do this? Will it just make things 10x more complicated?

You ask *what is good practice*, I have to say write a WPF application as simply as you can building on the lessons others have learned from doing this. To this end read up on [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), and use one of the base libraries to help, such as [Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Caliburn.Micro), [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) or [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

Comment: "Tier separation is a logical concern" : no ! Tier separation is a physical concern. So we can have different pieces of software running on different hardware. Now, I agree with the answer : if no real need to use delphi, just try and make it all in C#

Comment: Thank you so much, @AISki, understood, but my concern about separating them is to reuse the existing library, and the most important, to protect the business flow from the managed world

Comment: @Kek, Different pieces running at different times I agree with, but that is the driver. Without that need then I argue not to do it. Start with a single assembly, separate logically and only as you need to, separate physically.

Comment: @Leo.W If you have an existing library then it's a completely different scenario. Again I recommend doing only what you need to. You can always start with your C#/Delphi hybrid and as your needs change then you can re-visit that decision. In fact moving to C# solely would be a waste of effort until you hit a problem that **needs** you to more over. 
However I still wouldn't recommend that new projects are built in that way. :-)

Comment: @AISki, that's what i'm worry about, i don't if this will be a problem to rewrite the whole solution as i have not enough experience on it, but if it's a common model, life will be easy to me, but anyway, thank you

Comment: @Leo.W then I recommend starting with attempting to get C# talking to Delphi. If that works have a look at Laurent Burginon's work on MVVMLight as he details a variant where the model is a web service, and may give you similar issues to your scenario. Good luck